# Handling string search and substitution in R

Tags: r, string, text, substitution

I am a beginner in R, used Matlab before and I have been searching around for a solution to my problem but I do not appear to find one.
I have a very large vector with text entries. Something like

CAT06
6CAT
CAT 6
DOG3
3DOG

I would like to be able to find a function such that: If an entry is found and it contains "CAT" & "6" (no matter position), substitute cat6. If an entry is found and it contains "DOG" & "3" (no matter position) substitute dog3. So the outcome should be:

cat6 cat6 cat6 dog3 dog3

Can anybody help on this? Thank you very much, find myself a bit lost!

Comment: How do you know that "CAT 6" belongs together? Does your vector have some kind of delimiter?

Comment: The input shown is ambiguous.  Does it mean `"CAT06 6CAT CAT 6 DOG3 3DOG"` or `c("CAT06", "6CAT", "CAT 6", "DOG3", "3DOG")` or `c("CAT06", "6CAT", "CAT",  "6", "DOG3", "3DOG")` ?

Answer (score 0):

First remove blank spaces i.e. elements like "CAT 6" to "CAT6":

```
sp = gsub(" ", "", c("CAT06", "6CAT", "CAT 6", "DOG3", "3DOG"))
```

Then use some regex magic to find any combination of "CAT", "0", "6" and replace these matches with "cat6" as follows:

```
sp = gsub("^(?:CAT|0|6)*$", "cat6", sp)
```

Same here with **DOG** case:

```
sp = gsub("^(?:DOG|0|3)*$", "dog3", sp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The input shown in the question is ambiguous as per my comment under the question. We show how to calculate it depending on which of three assumptions was intended.

**1) vector input with embedded spaces**  Remove the digits and spaces (`"[0-9 ]"`) in the first `gsub` and remove the non-digits (`"\\D"`) in the second `gsub` converting to numeric to avoid leading zeros and then paste together:

```
x1 <- c("CAT06", "6CAT", "CAT 6", "DOG3", "3DOG") # test input

paste0(gsub("[0-9 ]", "", x1), as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", x1)))
## [1] "CAT6" "CAT6" "CAT6" "DOG3" "DOG3"
```

**2) single string** Form `chars` by removing all digits and scanning the result in.  Then form `nums` by removing everything except digits and spaces and scanning the result.  Finally paste these together.

```
x2 <- "CAT06 6CAT CAT 6 DOG3 3DOG" # test input

chars <- scan(textConnection(gsub("\\d", "", x2)), what = "", quiet = TRUE)
nums <- scan(textConnection(gsub("[^ 0-9]", "", x2)), , quiet = TRUE)
y <- paste0(chars, nums)
y
## [1] "CAT6" "CAT6" "CAT6" "DOG3" "DOG3"
```

or if a single output stirng is wanted add this:

```
paste(y, collapse = " ")
```

**3) vector input without embedded spaces**  Reduce this to case (2) and then apply (2).

```
x3 <- c("CAT06", "6CAT", "CAT", "6", "DOG3", "3DOG") # test input

xx <- paste(x3, collapse = " ")
chars <- scan(textConnection(gsub("\\d", "", xx)), what = "", quiet = TRUE)
nums <- scan(textConnection(gsub("[^ 0-9]", "", xx)), , quiet = TRUE)
y <- paste0(chars, nums)
y
## [1] "CAT6" "CAT6" "CAT6" "DOG3" "DOG3"
```

Note that this actually works for all three inputs.  That is if we replace `x3` with `x1` or `x2` it still works and as with (2) then if a single output string is wanted then add `paste(y, collapse = " ")`

Comment: @G.GrothendieckThank you very much for your input. I will think about your replies and come back to you!

Comment: @Aleksandr Voitov  Thank you very much for the input. Will look into it (need time to think as very new for me) and come back to you!